# Can't persist many to one relation in Spring with JPA (adding new parent entity instead)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to persist many to one relation through SpringMVC and JPA.

My view is the following:

## Add WordPair

```
  <form:form modelAttribute="wordpair" action="addWordPair" method="post">
        <label for="semanticUnitOne">Enter word one: </label>
        <form:input path="semanticUnitOne"/>
        <br/>

      <label for="semanticUnitTwo">Enter word two: </label>
      <form:input path="semanticUnitTwo"/>
      <br/>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dictionary">Dictionary</label>
          <form:select path="dictionary" cssClass="selectpicker" items="${dictionaries}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id">
              <%--<form:options items="${dictionaries}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>--%>
          </form:select>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add word pair"/>

  </form:form>

  <div class="control-group">
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller is the following:

```
@Controller
public class WordPairController {

@Autowired
WordPairService wordPairService;

@Autowired
DictionaryService dictionaryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "createWordPair", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createWordPair(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("wordpair", new WordPair());
    model.addAttribute("dictionaries", this.dictionaryService.findAll());
    return "addWordPair";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "addWordPair", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addWordPair(@ModelAttribute("wordpair") WordPair wordPair, BindingResult result, Dictionary dictionary) {

    wordPair.setDictionary(dictionary);
    wordPairService.save(wordPair);
    return "addWordPair";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "wordPairGet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String wordPairGet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wordPair", wordPairService.findAllWordPairs());

    return "wordPairGet";
}

}
```

Entitiy for dictionary is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Dictionary {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;
private String comment;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionary", cascade = CascadeType.All, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<WordPair> wordPairs;
```

and wordpair entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class WordPair {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String semanticUnitOne;
private String semanticUnitTwo;
private int rating;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.All)
private Dictionary dictionary;
```

Also there is a service and DAO,

```
@Repository("dictionaryDao")
public class DictionaryDaoImpl implements DictionaryDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Dictionary save(Dictionary dictionary) {
    em.persist(dictionary);
    em.flush();

    return dictionary;
}


public List<Dictionary> findAllDictionaries() {
    List<Dictionary> result = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dictionary d", Dictionary.class).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

}

```
@Repository("wordPairRepository")
public class WordPairDaoImpl implements WordPairDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public List<WordPair> findAllWordPairs() {
    List<WordPair> result = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM WordPair p", WordPair.class).getResultList();
    return result;
}

public WordPair save(WordPair wordPair) {
    em.persist(wordPair);
    em.flush();
    return wordPair;
}
```

The problem is when I try to persist `WordPair` and link `Dictionary` entity to it, hibernate persists new Dictionary entity and then persists new WordPair entity with attaching new dictionary to it. How to attach existing dictionary entity, which I have chosen with form:select item in view?
If I change

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.All)
```

option in WordPair to **Merge** or something, it gives

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing:

Comment: did you try to set wordPairs list in Dictionary object before persist Dictionary?

Comment: actually when I try to persist dictionary, everything is ok. I want to persist wordpair with existing dictionary and it persists, but with new dictionary empty dictionary entity (only with id)

Comment: You cannot `persist` an entity which is already persistent; need to use `merge`.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Spring JPA with Hibernate 5, I let hibernate create the tables.

I have entities:

```
@Entity(name = "DICTIONARY")
public class Dictionary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String comment;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="DICTIONARY_ID")
    private List<WordPair> wordPairs;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "WORDPAIR")
public class WordPair {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String semanticUnitOne;
    private String semanticUnitTwo;
    private int rating;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Dictionary dictionary;
```

I have JPA Repostories, note the @Transaction is important

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DictionaryRepository extends CrudRepository<Dictionary, Long> {
}
```

and

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface WordPairRepository extends CrudRepository<WordPair, Long> {
}
```

The tables created look like this :

```
DICTIONARY
    ID
    COMMENT
    NAME
WORDPAIR
    ID
    RATING
    SEMANTICUNITONE
    SEMANTICUNITTWO
    DICTIONARY_ID
```

The following tests shows I can do updates in both directions.

```
    Dictionary dictionary = makeDictionary("comment", "dictionary 1");
    dictionary.setWordPairs(new ArrayList<WordPair>());
    dictionary.getWordPairs().add(makeWordPair("George", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", 65));
    dictionary.getWordPairs().add(makeWordPair("Greg", "Unit 2", "Unit 1", 25));

    dictionaryRepository.save(dictionary);

    dictionary = dictionaryRepository.findOne(1l);
    assertEquals("dictionary 1", dictionary.getName());

    WordPair wordPair = wordPairRepository.findOne(dictionary.getWordPairs().get(0).getId());
    assertEquals("dictionary 1", wordPair.getDictionary().getName());

    wordPair.getDictionary().setName("dictionary 2");
    wordPairRepository.save(wordPair);

    wordPair = wordPairRepository.findOne(dictionary.getWordPairs().get(0).getId());
    assertEquals("dictionary 2", wordPair.getDictionary().getName());

    dictionary = dictionaryRepository.findOne(1l);
    assertEquals("dictionary 2", dictionary.getName());
```

Answer (score -1):

At first, you can remove `@ManyToOne` from wordPairs field, you just need to define the relationship in Dictory. And add `@JoinColumn(name = "dict_id")` to tell that the column in `wordPair` table for reference.

If it can not fix your problem, you should check the `wordPairs` data of dictory, whether the `id` field has value.

Check the code:

```
@Entity
public class Dictionary {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;
private String comment;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionary", cascade = CascadeType.All,       fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "dict_id")// the column name in WorPair table to refer Dictory.
private List<WordPair> wordPairs;
```

Comment: when I try to remove @ManyToOne annotation I have the following error during deployment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.masterwork.model.Dictionary, at table: WordPair, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(dictionary)]. As I read in previous posts, there is something wrong with cascadeType adjustments, but I can't define what is wrong.

Comment: Check my update, add `JoinColumn ` to set the reference column.

Comment: can you please show in code, because I'm confused a little bit

Comment: Now, I have the following mistake: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like JoinTable or JoinColumn: com.masterwork.model.Dictionary.wordPairs. If I remove mapping, then I get  Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.masterwork.model.Dictionary, at table: WordPair, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(dictionary)]

Comment: As said in error message remove `mappedBy = "dictionary"`

Comment: @ILya The JoinColumn tag should be in the entity that represents the table than contains the foreign key. In you case the one that stores WordPairs. WORD_PAIRS table (or whatever) should have a field idDictionary pointing to the id in the table DICTIONARY. You don't have to remove the mappedBy; you need to remove the JoinColumn from Dictionary.

Comment: For OneToMany setting, there are several kinds of ways, what you said is one way, my solution can also work. I prefer to set relationship setting in owner entity, 'Dictionary' class in this case.